# Match content before optional string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

Given the following string, I would like to produce: `A-2010`:

- `/Space/w_00123/A-2010/u_23`
- `/Space/w_00123/A-2010` (The /u_23 from above is optional, so missing here)

So the text between 3 and 4th / (if present, or until end of string) is what I really need.

I tried:

```sql
select
regexp_substr('/Space/w_00123/A-2010/u_23', '/Space/w_.+/(.*?)(?:/.+|$)', 1, 1, null, 1) r
from dual; -- this results in u_23 as opposed to A-2010
```

What's the right matcher expression here?

Comment: I believe what you need is `regexp_substr('/Space/w_00123/A-2010/u_23', '/[^/]+', 1, 3)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `regexp_substr` with 3rd appearance as the 4th argument gives what you need

```
with t(str) as
(
 select '/Space/w_00123/A-2010/u_23' from dual union all
 select '/Space/w_00123/A-2010'      from dual
)
select regexp_substr(str,'([^/]+)',1,3) as "Result Strings"
  from t;

Result Strings
--------------
A-2010
A-2010
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/MSWGKQ2468)</kbd>

Comment: Note this regex fails if a list element is null.  Test with a string of `'/Space//A-2010/u_23'`.  Treat as a delimited string and use this regex_substr format which handles NULL list elements: `regexp_substr(str,'(.*?)(/|$)',1,4,null,1)`. You don't want to silently return the wrong value from the list!

Comment: @Gary_W you're right, but due to the instructions of the question only the part after fourth slash and the rest is optional, implicitly upto that point all the leading part is required.

Comment: @Gary_W :D may be a nice future reference to use ... Thanks :))

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this using negated classes:

```
select
regexp_substr('/Space/w_00123/A-2010/u_23', '/Space/w_[^/]+/([^/]+)', 1, 1, null, 1) r
from dual
```

Online [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bfc3330802188ba774edd2a6caf4fdcd)